# Apache doesn't restart because of syntax error

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, debian

I got this:
Apache is not restarting because a syntax error. This is a screenshot of error. I installed recently apache and have not done any configuration.
[image]

This is my virtual host code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin informaticoerma@minag.cu
        ServerName www.erma.minag.cu

        <Directory /srv/ermaweb>
             <Files wsgi.py>
                 Require all granted
             </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess erma python-path=/srv/ermaweb
        WSGIProcessGroup erma
        WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/ermaweb/ermaweb2/wsgi.py

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static/ /srv/ermaweb/static/
        Alias /media/ /srv/ermaweb/media/

        <Directory /srv/ermaweb/static/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /srv/ermaweb/media/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

NOTE: Apache is installed recently and any configuration has been done.

Comment: What about reading the error message ? It tells you exactly what the issue is... (and this is not a programming question).

Comment: **"Invalid command WSGIDaemonProcess... perhaps defined by a module that is not loaded"** says your error.  Looks like mod_wsgi module isn't installed or loaded on your Apache instance. Look [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#loading-module-into-apache)